# ¿Como creo una librería que no me de error por estar redefinida?

Tags: c++

Hice una librería para crear un tipo de objeto, estos al ser de diferentes tipo tienen diferentes constructores, cada objeto ira a otras clases diferentes por lo cual lo cree como libreria para importarlas y de ellas crear el objeto en cada clase (estan en diferente codigo fuente) y estas son llamadas por otro archivo con un menu que será la encargada de acceder a los métodos de las clases que crean los objetos, pero al ejecutar da error de redefinicion por que lo importe a cada archivo fuente como lo soluciono, el principal problema es que necesito acceder a los atributos privados de la libreria en cada archivo de igual forma

---

```
//Nodo.h => libreria
class Nodo{
public: 
//Nodo para el cod Fuente de la clase Mapa
Nodo(string pCodPais, string pCodCiudad, string pNombre){
    codPais = pCodPais;
    codCiudad = pCodCiudad;
    nombre = pNombre;
    siguiente = NULL;
    anterior = NULL;
}

//Nodo para el cod. fuente de objetos de la clase Administrador
Nodo(string pCodPais, string pCodCiudad, string pPasaporte, string pNombre, string pEstadoMigratorio){
    codPais = pCodPais;
    codCiudad = pCodCiudad;
    pasaporte = pPasaporte;
    nombre = pNombre;
    estadoMigratorio = pEstadoMigratorio;
    siguiente = NULL;
    anterior = NULL;
}    
private:
Nodo *siguiente;
Nodo *anterior;

string codPais;
string nombre;
string codCiudad;
string pasaporte;
};
```

---

```
     //Archivo  clase Mapa

     #include nodo.h

     class Mapa{
Mapa(){
    primero == NULL;
}

void Mapa::insertarPais(string pCodPais, string pNombre){
if(listaVacia()){
    primero = new Nodo(pCodPais, pNombre);
    primero->siguiente = primero;
    primero->anterior = primero;
}
}
};
```

---

```
   //Archivo clase Administrador
   #include nodo.h
  class adm{

  void ListaAdmin::insertarAdmin(char pCodAdmin[], string pNombre){
    if(listaVacia()){
    primero = new Nodo(pCodAdmin, pNombre);
    primero->siguiente = primero;
    primero->anterior = primero;
   }

   };
```

---

```
  //Menu
int main(){
adm miAdm;
miAdm.insertarAdmin(.......);

mapa miMapa
miMapa.insertarPais(....);
}

//Necito acceder a los construtores y los atributos privados de Nodo.h
```

Comment: Tambien necesito una manera de que mis otras clases puedan acceder a los atributos privados de la libreria

Comment: Estás usando las [guardas de las cabeceras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), ¿verdad?

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un solo tipo y haciendo una union de datos.

Tu tipo Nodo tiene todo (cosas como: anterior, siguiente, y resto de mezclar los dos tipos)

Te recomiendo que uses 3 tipos (3 clases) distintos:

Nodo

NodoPais y que herede de Nodo

NodoAdm y que herede de Nodo

Comment: No veo cómo meter herencia en `Nodo` va a solucionar el problema de la redefinición